# Step function with Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Building a step function to orchestrate an ETL pipeline but keep getting this error. Here is my code and following below AWS docs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-etl-orchestration.html

```
 "GetStateOfCluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "lambda,
      "TimeoutSeconds": 180,
      "HeartbeatSeconds": 60,
      "Next": "IsClusterAvailable",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "ResultPath": "$.clusterStatus"
    },
    "IsClusterAvailable": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.clusterStatus",
          "StringEquals": "available",
          "Next": "runetljobs"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.clusterStatus",
          "StringEquals": "unavailable",
          "Next": "ClusterUnavailable"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.clusterStatus",
          "StringEquals": "paused",
          "Next": "InitializeResumeCluster"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.clusterStatus",
          "StringEquals": "resuming",
          "Next": "ClusterWait"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "DefaultState"
    },
    "DefaultState": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Error": "DefaultStateError",
      "Cause": "No Matches!"
    },
    "ClusterUnavailable": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "Redshift cluster is not available",
      "Error": "Error"
    },
    "ClusterWait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 900,
      "Next": "InitializeCheckCluster"
    },

    "InitializeResumeCluster": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "ResumeCluster",
      "Result": {
        "input": {
          "redshift_cluster_id": "redshift cluster id",
          "operation": "resume"
        }
      }
    },
    "ResumeCluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "lambda",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 180,
      "HeartbeatSeconds": 60,
      "Next": "ClusterWait",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "ResultPath": "$"
    },
```

It's directly going to default even cluster status shows 'available', rather it should go to runetljob stage. In the doc, they dont have default, if we dont add default, error is,

```
"cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'IsClusterAvailable' (entered at the event id #14). Failed to transition out of the state. The state does not point to a next state."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the state "runetljobs" defined in you state definition.